# Only change background color of one <a>

Tags: jquery

Actually i have this jquery code:

```
$(function() {
  $(".text").click(function() {
   $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
   $(this).css( "color", "red" );
   });
 });
```

What i would like to change is that, only the recent clicked a-tag with the class "text" has his color changed to red. Or better said that when an a-tag with the class text is clicked the color red from the last clicked a-tag is removed! To summarize: Only one a tag should have the red color at the same time!

Comment: To clarify: you want this to behave a bit like a radio button (only one is "selected") right? One hack is to clear all when any of them are clicked, then make the clicked one red.

Comment: Your title has background colour but you code has just colour, which is it?

Comment: @Floris how can i remove the color from all a tags in the class text?

Comment: And your actual HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `a` elements are siblings, for example:

```
<a class="demo" href="#">link one</a>
<a class="demo" href="#">link two</a>
<a class="demo" href="#">link three</a>
<a class="demo" href="#">link four</a>
```

I'd suggest:

```
$(".demo").click(function () {
    $(this).css('color', 'red').siblings().css('color','');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d7Nyu/1/).

But rather than manipulate the CSS directly it's easier to take the same approach and apply/remove specific classes:

```
$(".demo").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d7Nyu/2/).

If they're *not* sibling elements, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="demo" href="#">link one</a></li>
    <li><a class="demo" href="#">link two</a></li>
    <li><a class="demo" href="#">link three</a></li>
    <li><a class="demo" href="#">link four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I'd suggest:

```
$(function () {
    $(".demo").click(function () {
        $('a.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d7Nyu/3/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: I think this is the most comprehensive answer given.

Comment: Thank you very much for the compliment(s)! =)

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping the last clicked link in a variable?

```
$(function () {
    var lastClicked;
    $(".text").click(function () {
        $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
        if (lastClicked != undefined) {
            $(lastClicked).css("color", "");
        }
        lastClicked = this;
        $(this).css("color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

[Check demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ECC3k/1/). Of course, change the color from `"yellow"` to `"red"` (I used yellow because it calls more attention for the demo.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$(function() {
  $(".text").click(function() {
   $('.text').css('color','');
   $(this).css( "color", "red" );
   });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d7Nyu/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".text").click(function () {
        $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
        $(".text").css("color", "");
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the color from all other nodes first, see comment below...

```
$(function() {
    $(".text").click(function() {
       $(".text").css("color",""); // remove the color from all other nodes first
       $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
       $(this).css( "color", "red" );
     });
 });
```